# Need to exclude and match regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep, exec, bash-completion

i am new to bash and is trying to write a script that searches for some specific words in the codebase. But because there are a lot of false positives i also need to maintain a exclude_pattern list so that anything matching that is ignored
Currently  my script is returning the correct matches and the relevant line looks like this

```
output=$(find $sourceDir -path "*/.git" -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" \) -exec grep -E -H -i -R --color=always "$matching_regex" {} \; )
```

Now i am unable to use this output and run a exclude pattern on it i tried t do something like this but it did not work

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  foundFinal=$(grep -v "$exclude_matches" "$line")
done <<< "$output"
```

Maybe i do not need to do the exclude part separately but i could do both matching and excluding in the first command itself but i have so far been unsuccessful. Would be great if i can get any feedback or examples that could show me what i might be missing or doing incorrectly. Btw as already stated i am a newbie with bash, so if grep is not the command for my use case, please do not hesitate to comment.

Comment: why does your grep have `-R` or `--color==always` ?

Comment: @jhnc i am trying to geta  list of matching lines, the exclude is on previously found lines

Comment: --color=always highlights the matching word in a different color so that it is easy to decipher which word matched, my matching_regex contains multiple words ( same as exclude_matches) and looks like
matching_regex="\bFoo|"\
"\bBar\b|"\
"\bFoo1\b"
-R in the exclude phase might not be necessary i will remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output=$(
    find "$sourceDir" \
        -name .git -prune \
      -o \
        -type f \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) \
        -exec grep -E -H -i -- "$matching_regex" {} +
)
foundFinal=$(
    grep -E -v "exclude_matches" <<<"$output"
)
```

Or more efficiently, if you don't need `output`, just pipe the two together:

```
foundFinal=$(
    find "$sourceDir" \
        -name .git -prune \
      -o \
        -type f \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) \
        -exec grep -E -H -i -- "$matching_regex" {} + \
    | grep -E -v -- "$exclude_matches"
)
```

- I simplified the git check
- I replaced `\;` with `+` to reduce the number of invocations of `grep`
- I removed `-R` (which should never succeed anyway)
- I removed `--color==always` which could interfere with the second grep
- I added `-E` to the second grep to match the first one
- I added `--` to protect against regex that start with hyphen

If you want to colourize for display, you can re-run the grep on the (presumably not too long) result:

```
grep --colour=auto -E -i -- "$matching_regex" <<<"$foundFinal"
```

Comment: Thank you @jhnc this solution worked for me, i was also trying to pipe two grep commands together but bash was complaining about missing ;. can i ask you one follow up questions ( sorry might be a naive question) so as far as i understand exec command  ensures that the first grep shell command will not create a new process but since we are piping two grep commands and not specifying exec in the second one, will the second grep creates a new process.

Comment: `find ... -exec cmd ... {} \;` runs `cmd` once per file. using `\+` instead of `\;` then `cmd` runs once for a batch of files (which could be a large number

Comment: `touch a b c d e; find [abcde] -exec bash -c 'echo $$' -- {} \; ; echo --; find [abcde] -exec bash -c 'echo $$' -- {} +`

Comment: `find ... | grep` runs a single `grep` that takes all the input from whatever commands `find` runs (which in your case is one or more `grep`s.

Comment: If i understand correctly grep will run only twice in my case i.e `find ... -exec grep ... {} +` will run once only for the complete batch of files and than once that is completed the second grep will run to exclude matches, is my understanding correct OR `find ... -exec grep ... {} +` can run multiple grep commands the only thing guaranteed is that it will run on batch of files.

Comment: yes, as long as the batch is below a certain size but you should assume the `-exec` might happen multiple times: eg: `find / -exec bash -c 'echo $#' -- {} +`

Answer (score 1):

Using xargs & GNU Awk (untested)

```
# get files 
find "$sourceDir" -name .git -prune -o \
      -type f \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) -print0 |  
xargs -0 \
# piping find result (filenames) to awk 
awk -v mc="$match_regex" -v ex="$exclude_matches" '
    # filter matches and excludes
    match($0,mc) && ! match($0,ex)
    # display only line no filename
    # or --> match($0,mc) && ! match($0,ex){print FILENAME, $0}'
    # display filename && line
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `matching_regex.txt` contains all the regexes you want to include,
and `exclude_matches.txt` contains all the regexes you want to exclude.

try :

```
find $sourceDir -path "*/.git" -prune -o -type f\
    \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" \)\
    -exec grep -E -H -i --color=always -f matching_regex.txt {} + |
    grep -E -i -v -f exclude_matches.txt
```

Comment: `echo abcdef | grep --colour=always abc | grep -v bcd`